# How to intuitively interpret of topic distributions/coefficients in topic modeling

Tags: distributions, interpretation, topic-models, latent-dirichlet-alloc

I know topic modeling such as LDA can provide the distribution of topics in documents, and the distribution of topics represent the important of that topic. However, I'm having a hard time intuitively understanding what the distribution of topics corresponds to and what the interpretation should be? For example, imagine the topic coefficients are 0.5 topic A, 0.3 topic B, and 0.2 topic C for document 1. Is this a proper interpretation: document 1 spend 50% talking about topic A, 30% of the time talking about topic B, and 20% of the time talking about topic C? If not, what should it be? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's how we intuitively understand it, and you can also use the distribution of topics as a feature vector of a document.